# Starpoint Gemini 2 - Missing boarded ship

Tags: starpoint-gemini-2

I finally managed to board a ship while playing Starpoint Gemini 2.

I grappled it and was bringing it to the station when I realized that the ship was not in the grapple anymore.

It still shows in my HUD, but I can't find it. I tried to check all the tutorials but I can't find something that would point me to the ship, where I lost it.

Does anyone knows how to find a successfully boarded missing ship?

Here is a picture showing the ship:
[image: Boarded ship showing in the HUD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After capturing a ship the icon that appears on the right side of the screen (The one you've indicated in your screenshot) can be used to find the ship if the ship becomes ungrappled for whatever reason. Simply click on the right half of the icon (the one with the check) to select and easily find the ship as it will add way points for you to get to the ship.

The ship can become ungrappled if you are travelling too fast with it in tow. Larger ships mean you must travel slower in order to not lose the grapple. To avoid losing the ship in the future, you can select the ship (in the same manner as above) and then hit <kbd>k</kbd> which will change the camera to chase mode. You can use this to watch how far away the ship is. The further away it is the more 'stress' on the grapple. Once the ship's distance is more than your grappling range then you will lose the ship.